# SolR & wildcard. Allow partial keyword

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I'm trying to play with **wildcards features** in  SolR query process
I'd like to find all documents containing `fran*` text in my index.

So, why my wildcard syntax do not work ?

#### Query Details

Here is my JSON query body request

```json
{
  "params": {
    "q": "fran*",
    "rows":0,
    "defType": "edismax",
  }
}
```

I expect finding i.e. all documents containing France keyword.  But it finds only FRANS / FRAN? items, not any  item containing France.

If I query with search query `France` (without wildcat), it works perfectly.

#### Index Details

Target fields are indexed as text fields with some filters

```xml
<analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" articles="lang/contractions_fr.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/custom_stopwords_fr.txt" format="snowball" />
    <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
```

Comment: I've also tried to query on specific fields with `qf` param. successless.

Comment: When you're using a wildcard query, most filters in your chain will not be run (except those that are `MultiTermAware`), meaning that `fran*` is only matched against any _tokens_ in the index that start with `fran`. If the result of your filters change `france` into `fra` for example because of stemming/elision/etc, `fra` won't match `fran`. Use the `Analysis` page under Solr's admin panel to see exactly which tokens gets generated from your input string (the string stored for your document in the field), and you should be able to see that neither of those start with `fran`.

Answer (score 0):

`ElisionFilterFactory` and `FrenchLightStemFilterFactory` stem the terms. So if prefix in your input query doesn't match the stemmed term they won't match.

You can get around it by adding and `OR` clause between the full term and the prefixed term.

So your new JSON query body should be

```
{
  "params": {
    "q": "fran OR fran*",
    "rows":0,
    "defType": "edismax",
  }
}
```